# Admin's node set to published by default?

Tags: 6, nodes, workflows

I currently have nodes set to unpublished by default because I want to approve user submitted content before publishing it live. However, admins should have their nodes published by default. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Drupal 6.

Define a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) function in your custom module and set the '#default_value' of the status element to TRUE. This will only run if the user has the correct permission. This way, nodes can also be unpublished by unticking the 'Published' checkbox.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (user_access('administer nodes')) { // or other permission
        $form['options']['status']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Now your admin's nodes will be automatically published.

Thanks to andy for his comments.

Comment: Careful - this effectively _prevents_ the admin from being able to have unpublished content (whether they've ticked the checkbox or not): it would be better to simply change the default value of the published checkbox to be published. Also, rather than checking against roles, I think it's a bit nicer to check against a permission. And you're not gonna be checking against a single form ID, as each content type has its own node form.

Comment: You've raised some good points. However, even if #default_value was defaulted to published, wouldn't the problem of never being able to unpublish still exist? Perhaps we should check if the node has already been created. Also, do you mind explaining your last point some more?

Comment: Just kidding, #default_value works. Changing my answer.